# Npgsql & Postgresql : ERROR: XX001: could not read block 2354 of relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I have a service running and inserting data (a lot of data). Sometime, and this is only about few weeks,  I receive this error:

```
ERROR: XX001: could not read block 2354 of relation 1663/17633/17925: read only 0 of 8192 bytes.
```

This error is from the Npgsql connector of PostGresql:

```
Exception trace:    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.CheckErrors()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.CheckErrorsAndNotifications()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteCommand()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If I do the query that create that error inside PGAdmin, I have this error too. Anyone have an idea of why this Insert query that has nothing special has this error? This table has a primary key but not Foreign Key and I have verified manually, this table doesn't contain the primary key.

How can I solve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that error "XX001" is [listed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) as "DATA CORRUPTED" you probably need to reach for the backup.

Comment: What do you mean? The database is corrupted on the hard drive?

Comment: Most probably, but please ask on the appropriate pgsql list.